# Lamp package lamp-server^, auto enter mysql pw?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, lamp

Is there a way to pass the desired MYSQL password to the prompts in the `apt-get install lamp-server^` package in a single command line?

Note:
I tried finding the package repository to read up on it, but I can't find it.

Comment: **No**. This must be done when you'll configure your database after installation.

Comment: @muniz95 Actually, if you read the answer below you'll see that this isn't the case.

Comment: Well, living and learning...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can preset the password:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password your_password'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password'
sudo apt-get -y install lamp-server^
```

This is adapted from [a SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740571) which has a few variants on this idea.